# Keep socket.io room alive when all clients disconnect?

Tags: node.js, sockets

I have a multiplayer game with game rooms built in Node.js and socket.io. There are 4 players per game room and rooms are created when the first player joins. When I send data to a client connected to the room, I always perform the following check to make sure they're still in the room (`sock_id` is the socket ID of the client):

```
if(io.sockets.manager.rooms['/' + room].indexOf(sock_id) > -1){
    ...
}
```

If a player leaves the room, he is replaced by a robot player. However, I'm running into a problem when all 4 players disconnect. The room is automatically destroyed, and the above check throws an error `cannot call method indexOf of undefined`, indicating the room doesn't exist. One way to counter this is to add a check to make sure the room exists to every such check on the Node server (and there are quite a few).

But, I was wondering if it's possible to keep the room alive in some way even when all clients disconnect. I could then destroy the room when the game in question ends, and the problem is solved.

Comment: Where is the value 'room' coming from? If it is tied to the socket and the socket is destroyed on disconnection, it may not get you the room and hence the error.

Comment: `room` is the name of the room, in this case it would be "game" + game id, but that part is ok. The problem is that the room itself is destroyed after all the clients that were in it disconnect.

Comment: Direct from the wiki: 'Empty rooms will be automatically pruned so there is no need to manually remove them.'. Possible alternate can be you create a dummy socket client on room creation, possible through https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO-node-client